# How to find many files from txt file in directory and subdirectories, then copy all to new folder

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I can't find posts that help with this exact problem:

On Mac Terminal I want to read a txt file (example.txt) containing file names such as:
20130815 144129  865  000000 0172 0780.bmp
20130815 144221  511  000003 1068 0408.bmp
....100 more

And I want to search for them in a certain folder/subfolders (example_folder). After each find, the file should be copied to a new folder x (new_destination).

Your help would be much appreciated!

Chers,
Mo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code outsourcing service.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a piped command with a combination of `ls`, `grep`, `xargs` and `cp`.

So basically you start with getting the list of files

```
ls
```

then you filter them with `egrep -e`, `grep -e` or whatever flavor of `grep` Mac uses for their terminal. If you want to find all files ending with text you can use the regex `.txt$` (which means ends with '.txt')

```
ls | egrep -e "yourRegexExpression"
```

After that you get an input stream, but `cp` doesn't work with input streams and only takes a bunch of arguments, that's why we use xargs to convert it to arguments. The final step is to add the flag `-t` to the argument to signify that the next argument is the target directory.

```
ls | egrep -e "yourRegexExpression" | xargs cp -t DIRECTORY
```

I hope this helps!

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't read the question well enough, I updated to be match your problem. Here you can see that the `egrep` command compiles a rather large regex string with all the file names in this way `(filename1|filename2|...|fileN)`. The $() evaluates the command inside and uses the `tr` to translate newLines to "|" for the regex.

`ls | egrep -e "("$(cat yourtextfile.txt | tr "\n" "|")")" | xargs cp -t DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$ for i in `cat example.txt`
find /search/path -type f -name "$i" -exec cp "{}" /new/path \;
```

This is how it works, for every line within `example.txt`:

```
for i in `cat example.txt`
```

it will try to find a file matching the line `$i` in the defined path:

```
find /search/path -type f -name "$i"
```

And if found it will copy it to the desired location:

```
-exec cp "{}" /new/path \;
```

Comment: Hey nbari, I almost got it to work, but when it reads the file names it breaks them up since they have spaces. The filenames in the txt file are for instance: 20130902 221149  529  000000 0930 0570.bmp.  So when I echo, the read names I get 20130902 as one filename, 221149 as the next, and so on. I tried to use regexp so that terminal knows what to read as the filename, but I didn't get it to run. This is what I have so far: for i in $(cat /path/file.txt) | grep '^2013[0-9 ]+bmp'  ; do echo $i; done. Would you mind having a look please? I am quite unexperienced with regexp. Thanks

Comment: @MoritzSchmid I updated the answer, check the quotes around `{}`